# Encoding the HOG features

Tags: image-processing, histogram, gradient

I have got a video containing 200 frames and i am extracting low level features at pixel level. Then i am dividing the entire frame in to small spatial patches (say of size 7x7) and creating a feature vector for each spatial patch (by summing up the feature values of the pixel inside the particular patch). If i want to use the HoG features in the above mentioned procedure, what is the best possible way to do that? i.e using PCA? or shall i use the values of the bin for that particular 7x7 patch directly (say if i have 4 bins then it will be 4 feature variables)?

PS : i am using GMM to model the features. So i want the features of each patch can be correlated with one-another using euclidean distance measure.

Comment: Can you please explain what you're asking in more detail. I don't understand what the question is asking?

Comment: @PeterK.I have added more detail, could you please look in to this?

Comment: Its hard to understand what exactly you are asking. You can use HOG on a per frame basis for feature extraction, but you can also use it across frames as well via motionHOG. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Varo, Is this in the context of patch classification / detection or what?